# Porque passar argumentos para um Fragment usando Bundle ao inves de um método set

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Recentemente me fiz uma pergunta, aparentemente simples, que não consegui me responder e nem encontrei nenhuma resposta concisa.
A pergunta é simples: *Porque usar Bundle ao inves de um método set para passar parâmetros de uma Activity para um Fragment?*

Por exemplo:

Caso 1:

```
public static MyFragment getInstance(String myAttr){
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    myFragment.setMyAttr(myAttr);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Caso 2:

```
public static MyFragment getInstance(String myAttr){
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("myAttr", myAttr);
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Eu sempre uso o Caso 2 porque em todos os livros que li usam e aprendi assim.
Porém nenhum deles explica o porque de usar com Bundle.
Seria por causa do ciclo de vida da activity e do fragment o porque do uso do Caso 2?

EDIT:

Complementando a resposta do Ramaral.
Tem um exemplo que fica fácil perceber o porque é necessário usar o Caso 2 ao invés do Caso 1.
Basta fazer duas activities, A e B por exemplo. E dar `commit()` num fragment, instanciado como no caso 1, na activity A.
Ir nas opções de desenvolvedor, habilitar a opção "Don't keep activities".
Sobrescrever o método `onSaveInstanceState`.
Navegar da activity A para B e depois voltar para A, e verificar o bundle que vem como parâmetro da `onSaveInstanceState` é sempre nulo.

Comment: Sim, é por causa do ciclo de vida do próprio Fragment. Quando ele for recriado (e isto vai acontecer), o seu método (caso 1) não será chamado. Tem isso na própria documentação...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qualquer que seja a situação não é "aconselhável" que o estado inicial de um objecto seja determinado recorrendo ao uso de *"setters"*.

As "boas práticas" preconizam que o estado inicial de um objecto deve ser determinado na sua construção. O objecto deve ser construído recorrendo a um construtor que receba os valores necessários para o criar num estado inicial válido.

Um Fragment é um caso especial já que ele pode ser destruído e recriado pelo SO.
Como a única forma que o SO tem para o recriar é usar o construtor padrão, o Fragment pode não ser criado num estado inicial válido.

A forma que os programadores do Android encontraram para resolver essa situação foi disponibilizarem o método [setArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)).
O Bundle passado a ele deverá ser usado para colocar o Fragment num estado inicial válido. Ele substitui um eventual construtor que seria usado para o efeito.

Ao usar o método `setArguments()`, o SO, garante que o Bundle passado esteja sempre disponível ao chamar o método [getArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()), mesmo que o Fragment tenha sido destruído e recreado.

Comment: Valeu @ramaral. Minha dúvida ficava exatamente nesse ponto da inicialização do objeto.